# There is a word for "Something is about to happen" and it ends with -age. What is that?

Tags: nouns

There is a word for the meaning "Something is about to happen" and it ends with "age". And I have not used it for a very long time so forgot it. Can someone help me out with it??

Comment: Perhaps you mean *presage*?

Comment: Exactly, that's the word I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in (possibly ephemeral) comments, the OP was seeking the word **presage**, defined in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presage) as:

> 1: something that foreshadows or portends a future event :  omen
>
> 2:  an intuition or feeling of what is going to happen in the future
>
> 3 *archaic*:  prognostication
>
> 4:  warning or indication of the future